# TVOS UITextView not scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, tvos, apple-tv

`UITextView` in `TVOS` not scrolling, I can see its `contentSize` is great then its `bounds`, I can confirm that `scrollEnabled = YES`, `userInteraction = YES` and it is current focused view.

Comment: That what I did, was looking for some, work around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yourtextview.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = @[@(UITouchTypeIndirect)];
```

Fixed it for me.

Comment: yup I am using this also,  It also fixed for me :)

Comment: This solution is not available in tvos 10